# How to define alpha or alphanumeric rules for a ORM model using Kohana 3?

Tags: php, validation, orm, kohana-3

I'm doing this in my model....

```
   protected $_rules = array(
      'id' => array(
            'not_empty' => NULL,
            'numeric' => array(TRUE)
             )
....
```

Am I doing it right for the numeric qualifier?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it right.